# Python - Create a dictionary from the keys of two other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have functions that create two separate, sorted dictionaries.
Examples:

Dictionary_A

```
('a', 0.55)
(' ', 0.088)
('o', 0.088)
('>', 0.055)
('4', 0.055)
```

Dictionary_B

```
('c', 0.021)
('h', 0.031)
('u', 0.031)
('8', 0.024)
('y', 0.054)
```

In order to do some encryption testing, I need to create a third dictionary in which the first key in Dictionary_A is mapped to the first key in Dictionary_B and so on. The only caveat is that a character in Dictionary_A may map to more than one character in Dictionary_B, but two different characters in Dictionary_A may not map to the same character in Dictionary_B.

Dictionary_C, from these examples, would be something like:

```
{'a':'c', ' ':'h', 'o':'u', '>':'8', '4':'y'}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: dictionaries can't be sorted, and those are not dictionaries...

Comment: It seems like keys from B should map to keys from A, not the other way around...

Comment: Following up on juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, are you using custom classes for Dictionary_A and Dictionary_B? What behavior do you want if the mappings disobey the rules you outlined?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of what you mean with your caveat, and what that result would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your data looks like a list of tuples, not a dictionary. In valid python syntax, this would be:

```
list_a = [('a', 0.55),
    (' ', 0.088),
    ('o', 0.088),
    ('>', 0.055),
    ('4', 0.055)]

list_b = [('c', 0.021),
    ('h', 0.031),
    ('u', 0.031),
    ('8', 0.024),
    ('y', 0.054)]
```

Then a dictionary with first elements from `list_a` mapping to first elements of `list_b` can be created like this:

```
{k[0]:v[0] for k,v in zip(list_a, list_b)}
```

Which returns:

```
{' ': 'h', '4': 'y', '>': '8', 'a': 'c', 'o': 'u'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys have a natural ordering that you like, you can do something like

```
dict(zip(sorted(dict_a.keys()), sorted(dict_b.keys()))))
```

Or if you assume OrderedDict, you could do the same thing without the use of `sorted`

Your constraints don't make a lot of sense to me, since keys cannot repeat in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

This answer caters to the comment that "a character in Dictionary_A may map to more than one character in Dictionary_B, but two different characters in Dictionary_A may not map to the same character in Dictionary_B." This was ignored in the other answers because it does not make sense for a dictionary to have two of the same key.

It sounds like you have access or could easily obtain two sequences of keys. If so, then you can use `zip` and `defaultdict` to construct a mapping from the keys in A to lists of keys in B.

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
keys_b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

key_mapping = defaultdict(list)

for key_a, key_b in zip(keys_a, keys_b):
    key_mapping[key_a].append(key_b)

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '4'], 'c': ['3'], 'b': ['2']})
```

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate your help.